# VS Code сам убирает проставленные мной пробелы

Tags: visual-studio-code

VS Code сам убирает проставленные мной пробелы, искал ответы по данному вопросу, ничего не нашёл.

```
function html() {
    return
    // return src(path.src.html)
}
```

набираю код в редакторе, после return ставлю пробел и начинаю набирать src, редактор сам убирает поставленный мною пробел и на выходе получается returnsrc(слитное написание), так же при переходе на новую строку(enter) редактор сам возвращает курсор в конец строчки, как будто enter не был нажат. До этого работал - ни с чем подобным не сталкивался.

Answer (score 1):

Была та же проблема. Оказалось что проблема в расширении для VS Code - JS-CSS-HTML Formatter.